# How to extract hardcoded strings from a binary in Mac?

Tags: string, macos, cocoa, binary-data

Is there API available in any language that can run on a Mac (Perl/Python/Cocoa/etc) or command line tools you can use to load a binary (app/bundle/framework/etc) and extract the hard-coded strings used in the code?

The reason behind is we want to check if there are any hard-coded paths in our compiled binary.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes, you can just use the `strings` command line tool:

```
$ man strings

NAME
       strings - find the printable strings in a object, or other binary, file

SYNOPSIS
       strings [ - ] [ -a ] [ -o ] [ -t format ] [ -number ] [ -n number ] [--] [file ...]

DESCRIPTION
       Strings looks for ASCII strings in a binary file or standard input.  Strings is useful for identifying random object files and many other things.  A string
       is any sequence of 4 (the default) or more printing characters ending with a newline or a null.  Unless the - flag is given, strings looks in all  sections
       of the object files except the (__TEXT,__text) section.  If no files are specified standard input is read.

       The file arguments may be of the form libx.a(foo.o), to request information about only that object file and not the entire library.   (Typically this argu-
       ment must be quoted, ``libx.a(foo.o)'', to get it past the shell.)

       The options to strings(1) are:

       -a     This option causes strings to look for strings in all sections of the object file (including the (__TEXT,__text) section.

       -      This option causes strings to look for strings in all bytes of the files (the default for non-object files).

       --     This option causes strings to treat all the following arguments as files.

       -o     Preceded each string by its offset in the file (in decimal).

       -t format
              Write each string preceded by its byte offset from the start of the file.  The format shall be dependent on the single character used as the  format
              option-argument:

       d      The offset shall be written in decimal.

       o      The offset shall be written in octal.

       x      The offset shall be written in hexadecimal.

       -number
              The decimal number is used as the minimum string length rather than the default of 4.

       -n number
              Specify the minimum string length, where the number argument is a positive decimal integer. The default shall be 4.

       -arch arch_type
              Specifies  the  architecture, arch_type, of the file for strings(1) to operate on when the file is a universal file.  (See arch(3) for the currently
              know arch_types.)  The arch_type can be "all" to operate on all architectures in the file, which is the default.

SEE ALSO
       od(1)

BUGS
       The algorithm for identifying strings is extremely primitive.

Apple Computer, Inc.                                                    September 11, 2006                                                              STRINGS(1)
```

Comment: Will `strings` find `NSString` constants which are made-up of `unichar` characters, not 8-bit characters?

Comment: @trojanfoe: good point - it only works with ASCII I believe, so any strings containing wide characters will not be printed

Comment: That's OK. ASCII is ok for now. Thanks!

Comment: Additionally, if the binary is a universal binary (with multiple architectures), you may need to strip off and leave only one binary because the same strings will re-appear in the result N times where N is also the number of architectures packed in the universal binary.

Comment: @radj: you can use lipo for that.

Comment: @PaulR: I did use lipo since strings' -arch parameter doesn't seem to work.

Comment: The only problem with the strings command is it searches for "...characters ending with a newline or a null". That means you'll miss a lot of words if you go after any generic binary file, such as a Word document.