# How can I find private iOS API usage in my app?

Tags: ios, macos, xamarin, xamarin.ios, iphone-privateapi

My app was rejected from the app store for using the private API "LSApplicationWorkspace", but I can't find that in my source code. How can I find what library is using it? I'm using Xamarin.iOS on macOS.

Answer (score 3):

What you need to do is search through every library your app uses until you find the offending API string. In my case I was searching for LSApplicationWorkspace.

Here is a terminal command that will find every dll in your folder and execute '[strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8148841/how-to-extract-hardcoded-strings-from-a-binary-in-mac)' on it. The first option copies the results to your clipboard, the second option writes to a text file.

- Build your app.
- Open terminal.
- cd to the output directory (i.e. iPhone/Debug).
- Run the command below
- Search the results for the offending call.

Command

```
find . -type f -iname '*.dll' -exec strings {} \; | pbcopy
```

or

```
find . -type f -iname '*.dll' -exec strings {} \; > output.txt
```